# System.BadImageFormatException on production server. (Not related to 32/64 bit)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, sitecore

We have hosted the sitecore application on 4 servers. One of the servers started throwing System.BadImageFormatException. We restart IIS and it fixed our problem.
Now, We are trying to find the root cause of the problem. 
It is not related to 32 bit or 64 bit as 4 servers have the same configuration and the same code was deployed to all the servers. Only one server was throwing this exception.

Any help is much appreciated.

Below log was written for this exception:

```
7680 2019-05-12 14:48:21 ERROR Application error.

Exception: System.BadImageFormatException

Message: Bad method token.

Source: App_Web_tmoqb2wr
   at ASP.layouts_us_layouts_main_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Did you [significantly change .NET versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7319750/11683)?

Comment: No. I just restarted problem IIS on problem making server.